# Запуск desktop-приложения с передаваемыми параметрами

Tags: c#, desktop

Есть два desktop-приложения: **launcher**, который позволяет менять параметры второй программы, и **cleaner**, которой и передаются эти параметры. Необходимо через **launcher** вызвать **cleaner** с передаваемыми ему параметрами из `Settings.Settings`.
 Пытаюсь провести аналогии с вызовом консольного приложения, где ему можно передать параметры в `args[]`, но в desktop-приложениях не нашёл родных методов, которые позволили бы обработать аргументы. Собственно, к вопросам:
1) Подскажите, корректно ли передавать параметры из **launcher**, используя

```
 Process.Start( "Cleaner", parametres)
```

2) И самое главное - как и где их правильно принять в **cleaner**.
Премного благодарен.

Comment: [возможно вам поможет этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769113/how-to-start-wpf-based-on-arguments)

Comment: @Mirdin Вариант с XAML, увы, не подойдёт для десктопного приложения. Да и Environment разве позволяет получить параметры, с которыми запустилось приложение?

Comment: [вот еще](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179532/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-winforms-application), да и кстати, чем вам `WPF` не дектопное приложение

Comment: @MihailPirogovsky `desktop` приложение - понятие растяжимое, в большинстве случаев это `WPF` или `WinForms`. Вам дали решение для `WPF`, на `WinForms` все примерно так же, вы можете получить параметры таким путем `string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();`, либо переписать `static void Main()` добавив туда `static void Main(string[] args)`. Определитесь для начала, что за `desktop` приложение у вас и только тогда вам дадут нужный ответ.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ , действительно, у меня WinForms. Спасибо за ответ, помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Если вам надо просто запустить приложение с параметрами необходимыми, то да `Process.Start("app.exe", "parameter(s)");` вполне подходит для этих целей.

2) Для отлавливания параметров запуска в самом приложение `WinForms`:

- Либо переписываем строку `static void Main()`, на что то вроде `static void Main(string[] args)`
- Либо отлавливаем с помощью [GetCommandLineArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), тогда вам надо будет сделать что то на подобии `string[] args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();`